# How To Avoid If else Hell in NodeJs, Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am making a project in Nodejs and express i have a logic in response to a ajax call which query `MongoDb` database via its aggregate framework and then process the result so obtained.

Result obtained from `MongoDB` Query

```
  [ { _id: 'ALR', count: 7 },
  { _id: 'WTK', count: 3 },
  { _id: 'BWL', count: 9 },
  { _id: 'BAT', count: 9 } ]
```

Callback function for this query

```
, function (err, counts) {
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return res.json({status:false, msg : err});
              }
              if(counts){
                console.log(counts);
                for (var i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
                    var type = counts[i]._id;
                    var count = counts[i].count;
                    if(type == "ALR"){
                      if(count < 5){
                        return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 5 All-Rounders"});
                      } 
                    } else if(type == "BAT"){
                      if(count < 6){
                        return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 6 Batsman"});
                      } 
                    } else if (type == "BWL"){
                      if(count < 6){
                        return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 6 Bowlers"});
                      } 
                    } else if(type == "WTK"){
                      if(count < 3){
                        return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 3 Wicket Keepers"});
                      } 
                    }
                } 
                return res.json({status:true, msg : "Squad Lauched"});
              }
          });
```

looks like i am in a kind of If Else hell , this code work as expected but i am not satisfied with this if anyone can atleast give a hint of doing this callback function in a better way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is obviously very repetitive. One approach to change that is to create an object with the necessary data and do the program logic based on that. For example:

```
var types = {
  ALR: { min: 5, name: 'All-Rounders' },
  BAT: { min: 5, name: 'Batsman' },
  BWL: { min: 4, name: 'Bowlers' },
  WTK: { min: 3, name: 'Wicket Keepers' },
};

for (var i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
  var type = counts[i]._id;
  var count = counts[i].count;
  if (types[type] && count < types[type].min) {
    return res.json({ status: false, msg: 'Minimum ' + types[type].min + ' ' + types[type].name });
  }
}
```

Comment: you answer looks very small and clean...defiantly what i was looking for .....will be implementing this and follow up. Thank you very much for you time

Comment: this answer worked like a charm , thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Except for a `switch` case there isn't much you can do.

However you can cut a bit of code like so:

When you check for error `if (err) return;`
the code-block will the stop executing. So you don't have to check for the `if (counts)`. Instead, just continue writing code.

Example:

```
function (err, counts) {
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return res.json({status:false, msg : err});
              }
              if(counts){ //remove this if. Not needed
                console.log(counts);
                for (var i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
```

Becomes

```
  function (err, counts) {
                  if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.json({status:false, msg : err});
                  }

                    console.log(counts);
                    for (var i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
```

The same could be done with that inside the for loop, also putting the nested statements together with their parent, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
    var type = counts[i]._id;
    var count = counts[i].count;
    if(type == "ALR" && count < 5){
        return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 5 All-Rounders"});
    } 
    if(type == "BAT" && count < 6){
        return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 6 Batsman"});
    } 
    if (type == "BWL" && count < 6){
        return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 6 Bowlers"});
    }
    if(type == "WTK" && count < 3){
        return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 3 Wicket Keepers"});
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have chosen to `return` from all of your paths which identify a failure with the data then you don't need to use most of those `else` statements - simply continue to a subsequent `if`.

And you are performing two tests for each if which can be concatenated into a single check with 2 conditions and a boolean `&&`.

And your code doesn't handle the condition when there is no data. Given your approach of multiple returns, you can put that first and remove another level of nesting.

```
function (err, counts) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.json({status:false, msg : err});
    }

    if(!counts) {
        // only guessing at what you'd want to return here
        return res.json({status:false, msg : "There was no squad!"});
    }

    console.log(counts);
    for (var i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
        var type = counts[i]._id;
        var count = counts[i].count;

        if(type == "ALR" && count < 5){
            return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 5 All-Rounders"});
        } 

        if(type == "BAT" && count < 6){
            return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 6 Batsman"});
        } 

        if (type == "BWL" && count < 6){
            return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 6 Bowlers"});
        } 

        if(type == "WTK" && count < 3){
            return res.json({status:false, msg : "Minimum 3 Wicket Keepers"});
        } 
    } 

    return res.json({status:true, msg : "Squad Lauched"});
}
```

Comment: Unlike the other answers, there is no `switch` in mine because that only lets you react to a single value, whereas all of your conditions are based on 2 values. Therefore your code is not ideal for a switch as you would still need an if within each case.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

```
const squadTypeResolvers = new Map();
squadTypeResolvers.set('ALR', { 
  name: 'All-Rounders',
  minCount: 3,
});
squadTypeResolvers.set('BAT', { 
  name: 'Batsman',
  minCount: 6,
});
squadTypeResolvers.set('BWL', { 
  name: 'Bowlers',
  minCount: 6,
});
squadTypeResolvers.set('WTK', { 
  name: 'Wicket Keepers',
  minCount: 3,
});

function handleErrors(err, counts) {
  if(err){
    return res.json({status:false, msg : err});
  }
  if(counts){
    const errorMessages = [];
    counts.forEach((count) => {
      const squadMember = squadTypeResolvers.get(count._id);
      if (count.count < squadMember.minCount) {
        errorMessages.push('Minimum ' + squadMember.minCount + ' ' + squadMember.name);
      }
    });

    if (errorMessages.length > 0) {
      return res.json({
        status: false,
        msg: errorMessages.join('; '),
      });
    } else {
      return res.json({status:true, msg : "Squad Lauched"});
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can pass the array of error messages as an array in json to pass all errors conveniently to the user/consumer

Answer (score -2):

Simple. You can **use switch case** instead of multiple if else statements.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote or make the answer verified. It might be useful for other too. @GauravKumar

Comment: Don't know @VietPhan May be some random person

Comment: I gave a simple one line because there is no point in rewriting the above in switch case...

Comment: But if you had, you would have noticed that switch/case does not make the code any better :)

Comment: It would have code more readable. Switch is a good alternative for multiple if else statements

Comment: Then please add your suggested code to your answer. I honestly do not see how that would make the code from the question any better.

Comment: It is but it is also the same in essence. str's answer is actually a way better one than a switch